# Convert ANS.1 to DER and vice versa

Tags: c, asn.1, der

I have ASN.1 schema:

```
World-Schema DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= 
BEGIN 
AAA::=SEQUENCE 
{ 
a            INTEGER(0..4294967295), 
b           INTEGER(0..4294967295), 
s           OCTET STRING(SIZE(4)) 
} 
END
```

And data:

```
value AAA::=  
{ 
a 123,
b 321,
s '41414141',H
} 
END
```

What is the best way to convert ANS1 data to DER format and vice versa?

Comment: In an old project we used [ans1c](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c) to create C code that is able to encode and decode ASN.1 encoded packets. AFAIR we used PER but it should also be able to use DER. I wasn't involved in that part of the project and cannot really provide help.

Answer (score 1):

Most real world ASN.1 specifications are much more complex than the one you have displayed here and tend to grow bigger with time.  A commercial ASN.1 Tool is more likely to cover the complete ASN.1 workflow consisting of compiling the ASN.1 schema to ensure correct bindings, and then serializing (encoding and decoding) the data.  A good list of ASN.1 tools can be found at https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx which is part of the ITU-T ASN.1 Project.